# Attaching a light fixture without a box

Tags: wiring, lighting

I'm replacing a light fixture, but upon removing the old light I discovered the wires are not in a box. Can I just anchor the mounting plate to the drywall or is a box mandatory?

Answer (score 3):

There are instance where this is possible and legal, such as bathroom vanity bar type lights with an integral and complete back plate. Other than that a box is absolutely mandatory.

Here is a good example. Imagine these fixtures flush against the wall.
[image]

Comment: +1 Also recessed can lights routinely have an integral box.

Comment: @bib, absolutely right. No "additional" box is required in that case.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: yes, a box is required. Any electrical splices and connections must be enclosed appropriately and grounded if metal.